# Flask: Create routes dynamically

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a web page displaying information concerning items and trying to implement the following structures

```
 - /ITEMS
 |           + /ITEMS/ITEM_1
 |           + /ITEMS/ITEM_2
 ...
```

The route `/ITEM_LIST` contains an overview of all items and each `/ITEMS/ITEM_X` contains specific information about the given item.

Since my item list is *not* static, I would like to create dynamically the `ITEMS/ITEM_X` pages. For this purpose I have a function

```
def html_table_0(table: str, title: str = 'na'):
    return render_template('table_template.html',
                           tables=[table],
                           titles=['na', title])
```

This works fine when I have one specific item:

```
obj_name = obj.name  # (obj is an instance of custom class Obj representing my items)
@app.route('/objects/' + obj_name, methods=("POST", "GET"))
def html_table():
    return render_template('table_template.html',
                           tables=[obj.to_html()],
                           titles=['na', obj.title])
```

But it fails when trying to do this iteratively.

I tried to make use of this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417563/dynamically-generate-flask-routes/38418023):

```
counter, routes = 0, [None]*obj_array.__len__()
for obj in obj_array:
    routes[counter] = dict(route='/odds/'+obj.name,
                           func=lambda: html_table(table=obj.to_html()),
                           page=obj.name)
```

But this throws the exception

> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: `obj.name`

Any guidance would appreciated.

Comment: `@app.route('/objects/<object_id>')` and `def html_tables(object_id)`. This has to be a dupe, I need to find the canonical. In your template you want the link to point to `{{ url_for('html_table', object_id=object_id) }}` where the second `object_id` is passed when you render the tamplate

Comment: why to create many routes if you can create one with parameter.

Comment: Also see [the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules)

Comment: @roganjosh I see, thanks!